# Separate subject headings in list

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php require_once('Connections/pdoConnect.php'); ?>
<?php
// Issue the query
$pdo_recordset1 = $conn->query("SELECT id, title, author, subject FROM audio");
$pdo_recordset1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Audio List</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
// Now iterate over every row and display it
$n = 0;
while($r = $pdo_recordset1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<a href="PDO_detail.php?item=<?php echo $r['id']?>">
<?php echo ($r['subject'])?><?php echo ($r['title'])?><?php echo ($r['author'])?></a><br />
<?php
++$n;
}
if(0 == $n)
{
echo "Sorry there are no items to display";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This produces a list of all entries in the database. However I want to separate out the "subject" data as a heading above each title within that subject group. Eg:

SUBJECT 1

Title 1

Title 2

Title 3

SUBJECT 2

Title 1

Title 2

etc

How should I modify the above code to achieve this? I'm guessing it will need a nested loop, but not sure how to put this together.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the subjects into an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in one loop and then in for each subject in that array you can go through the whole list and echo the title and author if the subject matches.

```
$subjects = array();
array_push($subjects, $r['subject']);
```

---

usage requested so something like this though if someone could edit it to be correct and more efficient...

```
  <?php
  $subjects = array();$n=0;

  while($r = $pdo_recordset1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {array_push($subjects, $r['subject']);}

  while($s = $subject->$subjects)
  {
  while($r = $pdo_recordset1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    if($r['subject']==$s)
      {
      ?><a href="PDO_detail.php?item=<?php echo $r['id']?>">
      <?php echo ($r['subject']); echo ($r['title']); echo ($r['author'])?>
      </a><br /><?php
      }
    ++$n;
    }
  if(0 == $n){echo "Sorry there are no items to display";}
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Can't seem to make this work - where would this fit into the above code?